# Spotlight search result for contact does not open found contact in Address Book

Tags: macos, spotlight, contacts

When I search for a contact in Spotlight (Cmd-Space), the correct contacts show.

When I select a contact (Enter), Address Book opens, but it has no contact selected. I have to look for the same contact again, this time in Address Book.

I use this all the time and am certain it used to work. Have tried rebuilding Spotlight index by removing Address Book from Spotlight and re-adding it.

Anyone else have this issue? Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Are you sure the app that is launched is called Address Book? It should be called Contacts now.

Comment: It's Contacts.app, butt responds to Address Book too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by brute force.

1. Open Spotlight in System Preferences.
2. Remove everything except PDF.
3. Add my home folder to excluded items in Privacy tab.
4. Reboot.
5. Open Spotlight.
6. Remove my home folder from excluded items in Privacy tab.
7. Add Contacts to items indexed by Spotlight.

Presto, it's working again. I hope it keeps working.

Comment: not even need to reboot or deselect all checkbox in Spotlight prefs. Just add the home folder to the excluded items, wait 1 min and remove it from excluded items. Wait a couple of minutes, it should be fixed.
This is more or less the procedure given by Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716